# Subject-verb agreement question after WHAT

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, what

I have a question about how the verb LOOK below should be conjugated:

1.There are neatly-dug beds filled with what *look* like carrots, chard and kale...

2. There are neatly-dug beds filled with what *looks* like carrots, chard and kale...

Should LOOK agree with WHAT or with the vegetables?

Thank you.

Comment: Either one works. If the speaker considers the vegetables as a unit, it's singular; if the speaker considers the vegetables individually, they're plural.